# Intellij maven imports have broken classpath

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I'm using Intellij 13, I've been using Maven quite happily for awhile now to manage the JAR dependencies.

But the last few I've imported are causing a broken classpath issue, and they're not being installed to the repository.

I though it might be just the JSONPath library, but when I tried to install Selenium drivers it also happened with those libs. I checked the local repository and the directories exist, but the JARs haven't downloaded.

This only started happening recently, and a lot of other dependencies have been installed fine (but not since this issue started happening). I'm really not sure what might have caused it.

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this? Or why the JARs aren't installing? And can I just trigger an update somehow from Intellij to try to reinstall them?

[image]

Quick Edit Here:

I tried installing the modules using Intellij's "add library" feature. It installed them fine, whereas before I was just updating them directly in the pom.xml and it was downloading them.

The library feature seems a little better because it automatically adds them to my output artefacts anyway, but it would be nice if it also updated the pom so I can use it outside of the intellij environment.

So I'm not sure why updating the pom.xml isn't working any more...

Comment: Is this actively causing an issue with your development?  I've seen those sorts of errors pop up before but they've rarely been a hindrance.

Comment: I"m not sure, I have a classpath issue on HttpClient from an integration test that may or may not be related. I wanted to resolve this so I can isolate that issue from this problem

Comment: IntelliJ 13?  They've modified their versioning.  The current version is 2022.1.  I'm worried that you're using a badly out of date IntelliJ.  What version of Maven are you using?  What does "install the JARs" look like?  I would expect to see them in my local .m2 repository.  IntelliJ would show them as external libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem with the Community version of IntelliJ Community edition. I was able to solve the problem using this process:

1. Click "Help" menu
2. Click "Find Action" and type "Maven Settings."
3. Click "Maven Settings."
4. Click the arrow next to "Maven" on the left hand side, to see the submenu
5. Click "Importing"
6. Check "Import Maven Projects automatically" and click "OK."

[image: Partial screen shot of "Maven Settings" screen]

This should pull in all of the Maven dependencies from the pom.xml file, without you needing to manually add the libraries.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

I've had this issue in IntelliJ IDEA 2017 Ultimate.

After changing dependency versions, the IDE was unable to fix the path on its own. I went to my ~/.m2 directory and deleted all of the dependencies for the problem jar and then executed the "ReImport All Maven Projects" action. When it was complete, the dependency issue was resolved.

Comment: This is the way to go! Thank You! What may additionally help is to click on the `[Fix]` message in all messages from `File->Project Structure..->Problems` list and remove all of the paths colored in red. After that, go do the manual directory cleanup. :)

Comment: just that sometimes, there are no problems visible so Fix can be clicked :/

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered a problem like this.

I resolved it as follows:

```
Project Structure >> Modules >> your module has problem >> Dependencies
```

then double click the jar that have problem, go to "**Configure Project Library**",

and then click "+", i.e. I add dependency jar manually, otherwise, the dependency jar is red (i.e failed status) or have none.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really an answer, but I moved some stuff around the POM's and it seems to be working. I've got a bad internet connection, and I found that it kept stalling trying to download some of the jar files, and Intellij didn't seem to time out when it did stall, I ended up having to restart it each time it stalled to get the JAR's to download.

But it's working okay now by just editing the pom files, which is more convenient for me than libraries.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was having this exact problem because I was trying to import a local jar-with-dependencies without classifier. To solve this I just needed to add   **`<classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>`** to the maven dependency, e.g.:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

There can be different root causes of this issue.  For me problem was that I had a maven settings file with a different name.  Problem resolved after I went to intellij maven settings and updated the maven settings file path and then after maven refreshed my projects.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the probelm by deleting it in module dependencies, and then importing it again.