# Spring Boot WebSocket

Tags: java, spring-boot

In summary, Intellij tells me that no MessageMapping and SendTo annotations could be found!?

I included the sprint-boot-starter-websocket like that:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

After i implemented a websocket controller intellij tells me that there are no MessageMapping and SendTo annotations found.

```
@Controller
public class WebSocketController
{
    @MessageMapping("/chat/{topic}")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public String send( @DestinationVariable("topic") String topic, Message message){
        return "test";
    }
}
```

I also tried to include:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

but that did not work too.

What do i wrong?

EDIT:

In project structure>modules>dependencies a error message say

```
Library 'Maven: org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.0.7:RELEASE' has broken path.
```

What does that mean?

Comment: What import did you use? `import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;`?

Comment: Yes after the auto import failed, i tried with that path.

Comment: Then I don't know what to tell you. I added the `spring-boot-starter-websocket` dependency you gave above, imported the class, added the `@MessageMapping` annotation to a method, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I also tried a reimport but intellij wont find it. :/

Comment: Maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516056/intellij-maven-imports-have-broken-classpath

Comment: Yes, after deleting the .m2 folder it worked for me. Thank you :D